# How can I get control in DataTemplate?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, datatemplate

So, I have a code:

```
<tool:LongListSelector x:Name="citiesListGropus" Background="Transparent" 
   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource citiesItemTemplate}"                    
   GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource groupHeaderTemplate}" 
   GroupItemTemplate="{StaticResource groupItemTemplate}" Height="468" Margin="0,68,0,0">
      <tool:LongListSelector.GroupItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <tool:WrapPanel/>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </tool:LongListSelector.GroupItemsPanel>
</tool:LongListSelector>
```

And have a `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="groupHeaderTemplate" x:Name="groupHeaderTemplateName">
   <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Width="75" Height="75" Margin="-333, 15, 0, 15" x:Name="groupHeaderName">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="40" Foreground="White" Margin="15, 15, 0, 0"/>
   </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

How can I change a property `Visibility` of `Border` in `DataTemplate` ? I want to hide `DataTemplate`. But I can't bind my data to a property such as `TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"`, because I make binding data once, then I need to change some properties after data binding.

Any Ideas?

**UPDATE 1**

So, my main goal is filter the list of cities. I want to filter them by name.

My algorithm:

1) I get data from `WebService`.

2) Load my `ViewModel`

```
  if (!App.CitiesViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
     {
         App.CitiesViewModel.LoadData(serviceResponse.Result);
     }
```

3) Group the cities by name. My code like [this code](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api).
This is important, especially for `LongListSeletstor` I have to use templates.

Ok, my data ready. Now I do not need a web service.

```
<!-- The template for city items -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="citiesItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel Name="PlacePanel" 
                Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17" 
                Tag="{Binding Id}"  Visibility="{Binding IsVisibility}">
                <Image Height="75" Width="75" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,9,0" Name="Image" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                <StackPanel Width="311">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

I have `TextBox`, when I type name of a city - unnecessary cities hide. I can use data binding and `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so I can hide cities.

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           TextBox name = (TextBox)sender;

           foreach(var place in App.CitiesViewModel.Items
               .Where(city => (city.Name.Contains(name.Text)) && (city.IsShow == true)))
           {
               city.IsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
           }
           foreach (var city in App.CitiesViewModel.Items
               .Where(city => !city.Name.Contains(name.Text)))
           {
               city.IsVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
           }
        }
```

But I have some problems, I can't hide this `DataTemplate` when I search cities:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="groupHeaderTemplate" x:Name="groupHeaderTemplateName">
   <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Width="75" Height="75" Margin="-333, 15, 0, 15" x:Name="groupHeaderName">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="40" Foreground="White" Margin="15, 15, 0, 0"/>
   </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

When I type name of a cities I want hide `GroupHeaderTemplate`. When `TextBox` lost focus show `GroupHeaderTemplate`. 
[image]

I borrowed this picture [here](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api).

**Update 2**
My mistake was that I did not use `PropertyChangedEventHandler`. After adding this to GroupCity property and implementing an interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` I can change property `Data Template` after data binding.

```
private IList<Group<City>> citiesCollectionGroup;

    var cityByName = from city in App.ViewModel.Items 
group city by Convert.ToString(City.Name[0]).ToLower() 
into c orderby c.Key select new
 GroupCity<CitiesViewModel>(Convert.ToString(c.Key[0]).ToLower(), c);    
citiesCollectionGroup = cityByName.ToList();
this.citiesListGropus.ItemsSource = citiesCollectionGroup;  

public class GroupCity<T> : IEnumerable<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public GroupCity(string name, IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            this.Title = name;
            this.IsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            this.Items = new List<T>(items);            
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            GroupCity<T> that = obj as GroupCity<T>;

            return (that != null) && (this.Title.Equals(that.Title));
        }

        public string Title
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        private Visibility _isVisibility;
        public Visibility IsVisibility
        {
            get
            {
                return _isVisibility;
            }
            set
            {
                _isVisibility = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsVisibility");
            }
        }

        public IList<T> Items
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (null != handler)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #region IEnumerable<T> Members

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.Items.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable Members

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.Items.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Xaml code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="groupHeaderTemplate" x:Name="groupHeaderTemplateName">
   <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" Width="75" Height="75" Margin="-333, 15, 0, 15" x:Name="groupHeaderName" Visibility="{Binding IsVisibility}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="40" Foreground="White" Margin="15, 15, 0, 0"/>
   </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now we can change `Visibility` groupHeaderTemplate.

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GroupCity<CitiesViewModel> city in citiesCollectionGroup)
            {
                city.IsVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            //
        }



private void SearchText_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GroupCity<CitiesViewModel> city in citiesCollectionGroup)
            {
                city.IsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            //
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With "How can I change a property Visibility of Border in DataTemplate ? I want to hide DataTemplate. " I understand that you want to change the visibility of an item based on a property, see example below.

*(If the code below isn't quite the solution you are looking for please provide some more information about what you are trying to achieve. Re-reading your question and the comments I got on this example I doubt this is what you want to do, but I don't want to guess so I'm simply answering my interpretation of your question).*

With bindings you can:

1. Bind the visibility property directly to a a property of type Visibility (example with listbox and Person1)
2. Bind the Visibility property to a boolean property, and use a converter to convert that to the Visibility type (listbox2 and Person2 + BoolToVis class).

There are more ways, but this are the two most simple to implement in my opinion.¨

result of code below:
[image: screen shot of VS]

View:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="VisibilityWP.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
xmlns:VisibilityWP="clr-namespace:VisibilityWP"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.Resources>
                <VisibilityWP:BoolToVis x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Height="300">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Width="200" Visibility="{Binding Visibility}" Background="Blue">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="40" Foreground="White" Margin="15, 15, 0, 0"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
            <ListBox x:Name="listBox2" Height="300">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Width="200" Visibility="{Binding ShowBorder, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Background="Red">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="40" Foreground="White" Margin="15, 15, 0, 0"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
namespace VisibilityWP
{

    public partial class MainPage 
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            listBox.ItemsSource = new List<Person1>
                    {
                        new Person1 {Name = "Iris", Visibility = Visibility.Visible},
                        new Person1 {Name = "Somebody", Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed},
                        new Person1 {Name = "Peter", Visibility = Visibility.Visible},

                    };
            listBox2.ItemsSource = new List<Person2>
                    {
                        new Person2 {Name = "Iris", ShowBorder = true},
                        new Person2 {Name = "Mia", ShowBorder = true},
                        new Person2 {Name = "Somebody", ShowBorder = false}
                    };
        }
    }

    public class Person1
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Visibility Visibility { get; set; }
    }
    public class Person2
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool ShowBorder { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class BoolToVis : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (value is bool && (bool)value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that Alexandr is likely to see gaps in his list this way. He likely wants to filter out some items.

Comment: @Iris this looks like it's formatted fine to me (saw your tweet).

Comment: I'm actually a bit confused with the question, is he asking for how to retrieve resources during runtime, filtering/grouping, or the visibility? I interpreted the question that he wanted to change the visibility property using bindings. That can be done, but with that said it might not be the best thing to do if the intention is to filter data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, with your permission, I will fully describe its mission, what I want to do. My full code in update.

Comment: @IrisClasson so, it seems you are right. But the key point is the use of INotifyPropertyChanged for Groups. In Update 2 solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own simple DataTemplateSelector to do this. Check [this](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/implementing-windows-phone-7-datatemplateselector-and-customdatatemplateselector) out for more information.

Comment: Thank you! I check this article now. In example I can change property Foreground of TextBlock. But, I don't understand, how we change this?