# Why i can't get the "bar" in code behind? Because i put in to data templete? How can i access?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, computer-science

```
 <DataTemplate x:Name="SoundTitleTemplate"> 
    <ProgressBar x:Name="bar" Visibility="Visible" Height="0" Margin="20,30,130,0" />
 </DataTemplate>
```

in cs

```
    private void _webClient_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_downloadCanceled)
                return;

            if (bar.Value <= bar.Maximum)
            {
                bar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
                bar.Text = string.Format("{0}%", e.ProgressPercentage);
            }

        }

    }
```

I got search any this topic, but no get help :(
If you have any method, please show me, i try what i found, in the end is fail ~.~

Comment: You don't "access" the UI elements inside a `DataTemplate` in XAML using procedural code. Use DataBinding instead.

Comment: How to do that? i sound hard...

Comment: not too hard: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207023%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer can help you: [How can I get control in DataTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958743/how-can-i-get-control-in-datatemplate)

Also article about getting access to cotrol in DataTemmplate(but for WPF):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/04/16/how-do-i-programmatically-interact-with-template-generated-elements-part-ii.aspx